# Staging environment for distributed system

Tags: architecture, distributed-computing, distributed-system, system-design

I am working on a distributed system that consists of several core components which help building data pipelines that are used to run data processing jobs on big amount of files. In order to run the jobs, hundreds of workers are used.

Currently, I am working on building a staging/testing environment for the project, so we can test the behavior of the changes before pushing them to production. My approach at the moment is to have a 1:1 clone of the core components as well as few workers, however, this does not seem to be a good environment to test all the functionalities of the system, like the scheduler behavior on the large scale and so.

Is there any place where I can find best practices to build staging environment for such systems? The same question also goes for development environment.

Answer (score 1):

There is an important difference here between performance testing and functional testing.

Generally, on a dev environment you can test things out during the development phase, to make sure configs are okay, etc.

On a stage environment, you can functionally test things on the app version that is very close to production version. Usually, the stage env should have the app version after it was reviewed and merged in the master branch.

Now the limitation you're mentioning refers to performance testing, which is more costly because you need to replicate the scale of the production environment (ideally). So if this kind of testing is critical for your project, then you simply need a clone of the production environment with mocked data (files).

Generally, stage env is used to test the application from a functional perspective (for a given input, it generates the expected output). So you can have 2 or 3 workers here and some files that activate the use-cases you need.

Comment: Yes, this is my current approach, but I felt it is not enough, but maybe what I am missing is in fact the performance testing.  So what would you recommend to test the performance of such systems? Should this be done on the production env for example?!

Comment: Performance testing should be done in a separate environment, because if you do it in the production env, you may affect the production data being processed.